# Finding maximum of the basic Bernstein Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, optimization

The basic Bernstein Polynomials $B_{n, k}$ are defined for all integers $n, k$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$ by $B_{n, k} = {n \choose k} x^k (1 - x)^{n-k}$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

I want to prove that the maximum of $B_{n, k}$ occurs when $x = k/n$. The trouble is, the only definition of "maximum" and "minimum" we have defined so far is the obvious definition: that $f(\arg \max) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$ that the function is defined on. I'm not sure how to do prove that $B_{n, k} (k/n) \geq B_{n, k} (x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the derivative and set to zero to get local maxima and minima (by calculus 1) which gives you

$${n \choose k} (kx^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k} - (n-k)x^k (1-x)^{n-k-1}) = 0$$

Clearly the maximum doesn't occur when $x = 0,1$ so you can divide by the common factors of $x$ and $(1-x)$ and you can also ignore the constant ${n \choose k}$ and then you get

$$ k(1-x) - (n-k)x = 0$$

and you can verify that $x = k/n$ is the solution to this equation.

Comment: That's the problem: we have not yet established calc I rules of differentiation and finding max/mins, and I don't know how to do so without this.

Comment: @Soke ok, I'll think about this and see if there is a clever basic way to do it with just the arithmetic-geometric inequality or something like that. I'm assuming you can use those kinds of tools? Or maybe someone will post a very basic non-calc solution before I do.